# Firease Realtime Database cannot register new user

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to resolve one issue, I am trying to register new user by using my app, I am receiving no error message, however new user is not appearing  in database, here is my code for registering activity:

```
//check if user already exists
if (dataSnapshot.child(regLogin.getText().toString()).exists()) {
    showMessage("user name already taken!");
    btnRegConfirm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBarRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else{
    User newUser = new User(regEmail.getText().toString(), regPassword1.getText().toString(), regPhone.getText().toString(), regFirstName.getText().toString());
    table_user.child(regLogin.getText().toString()).setValue(newUser);
    showMessage("Registration Completed!");
    finish();
}
```

here is code for my User Class:

```
package com.example.danie.dine.Model;

public class User {

private String email;
private String firstName;
private String login;
private String password1;
private String phone;

public User() {

}

public User(String email, String password1, String phone, String name) {

    email = email;
    password1 = password1;
    name = firstName;
    phone = phone;
    login = login;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String regEmail) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password1;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password1 = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
}
```

any help will be much appreciated
read and write set to true in database

DB structure:

```
    {
  "User": {
    "daniel86": {
      "firstName": "daniel",
      "email": "daniel@test.com",
      "phone": "+123123123",
      "password": "123456"
    },
    "admin2018": {
      "firstName": "admin",
      "email": "admin@test.com",
      "phone": "+123123123",
      "password": "000111"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure, and respond with @PradyumanDixit

Comment: sorry, DB added. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with this, please check if the read/write rules are set properly and `table_user` is defined as it should be

Comment: Thanks for checking this for me! Yeha it is very weird as no error message comes up... Would there be any chance for my OS blocking something from being send to db?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, are your firebase security rules set to true for both reading and writing?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution...

the problem was with my User class (getters and setters)
So instead of having user constructor as on previous code snipset, I have done this:

```
 public User(String email, String password1, String phone, String name) {

    this.email = email;
    this.password1 = password1;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.login = login;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String regEmail) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password1;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password1 = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

}

Everything goes fine now!